# NIFI : Cant run Fat Nar

Tags: maven, apache-nifi

I am trying to run a fat/uber nar in nifi. I have nifi 1.4.0 and here is my pom

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>asd.zxc.qwe</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-extras -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
            <classifier>shaded</classifier>
            <version>3.1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-mock</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                <artifactId>nifi-nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>
                    shade
                </goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>fat</shadedClassifierName>

                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shaded.guava</shadedPattern>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com.google.**</include>
                            </includes>

                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com.google.common.base.Optional</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.google.common.base.Absent</exclude>
                                <exclude>com.google.common.base.Present</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>

                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

i can build it just fine. then i place the jar into the `lib` folder where nifi is installed. When i run nifi i get

```
2018-01-26 10:38:35,243 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./work/nar/extensions/.DS_Store/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (Not a directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./work/nar/extensions/.DS_Store/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (Not a directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarBundleUtil.fromNarDirectory(NarBundleUtil.java:44)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders.getNarDetails(NarClassLoaders.java:298)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders.load(NarClassLoaders.java:157)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders.init(NarClassLoaders.java:112)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:137)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:268)
2018-01-26 10:38:35,244 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2018-01-26 10:38:35,244 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

Comment: Why is the MANIFEST in *.DS_Store*?

Comment: Take a look at @Bryan's answer and you have to use the NAR which would have the processors' JAR inside and place it in lib directory.

Answer (score 5):

In order to build a correct NAR you should be using NiFi's NAR Maven plugin which will generate the appropriate MANIFEST file for you.

There is a Maven archetype that will setup the appropriate project structure for your. This page should have everything you need:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Maven+Projects+for+Extensions